# Estado de componente no se actualiza al cambiar estado de REDUX (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, redux

Tengo una pagina que permite hacer comentarios, borrarlos y modificarlos. El problema es que cuando se intenta modificar un comentario, en la base de datos y en el store de REDUX el cambio se refleja bien, pero no logro poder pasar el nuevo array de comentarios (con el comentario ya modificado) al estado del componente para que lo renderice automaticamente, con lo cual tengo que recargar el componente para poder notar el cambio en la pantalla.

EDIT: La modificacion del comentario se hace desde otro componente llamado en el render y se almacena el nuevo array con el comentario modificado en el store

```
class Activity extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            value:'',
            comments: [],
            activities: [],
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        console.log(this.state.comments)

    }


    componentWillUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { comments } = this.props.comments; 
   //Hasta aca en las props se ve que el comentario ya esta modificado

        if(prevProps.comments.comments !== comments) {
          this.setState({ comments: comments }) 
       //Al llegar aca entra correctamente al if pero no asigna nada al 
       //estado del componente
        }
      }

    async componentDidMount(){
        await this.props.getActivities(this.props.id)
        this.setState({activities: this.props.activity.activities})

        await this.props.getComments(this.props.id)
        this.setState({comments: this.props.comments.comments})
   //Aqui setea correctamente al estado
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmit =  async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            author: this.props.auth.user.userName,
            comment: this.state.value
        }

        await this.props.putComments(this.props.id, data);

        this.setState({comments: this.props.comments.comments})
        //Aqui tambien
        this.setState({value: ''})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div id="carrouselAct">
                {this.props.activity.loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : 
                    <div>
                        <Carrousel act={this.state.activities} />
                        <div id="comments">
                            {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated ? 
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <input 
                                        type="text" 
                                        name="comment" 
                                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                                        placeholder=" add a comment..." 
                                        value={this.state.value} 
                                        id="commentInput">    
                                    </input>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                                </form> :
                                <div></div>
                            }
                            {this.state.comments.map((comment, i) =>
                                <Comment get={this.getComments} com={comment} id={this.props.id} index={i} />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div> 
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     activity: state.activity,
     comments: state.comments,
     auth: state.auth
});


export default connect (mapStateToProps,{getActivities, getComments, putComments})(Activity);
```

Comments.js

```
class Comment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value:'',
            author: props.com.author,
            comment: props.com.comment,
            i: props.index,
            isEliminated: false,
            toUpdate: false,
        }

    }


    handleDelete = () => {
        const data = {
            author: this.state.author,
            comment: this.state.comment
        }
        axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/itinerary/comments/deletecomment/${this.props.id}`, data);
        this.setState({isEliminated: true})
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }

    handleUpdate = () => {
        this.setState({toUpdate: true})
     }

    submitUpdate = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            author: this.state.author, 
            comment: this.state.value,
            i: this.state.i
        }

        this.props.updateComment(this.props.id, data)
        this.setState({toUpdate: false})        
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.isEliminated ? 
                    <div className="deletedComment">
                        <p>Deleted</p>
                    </div>
                    :
                    this.state.toUpdate ? 
                        <div>
                            <form onSubmit={this.submitUpdate}>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    value={this.state.value} 
                                    placeholder={this.state.comment}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                                    id="commentInput">
                                </input>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update"></input>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        :
                        <div className="comment">
                            <div className="commentInfo">
                                <p className="authorP">{this.state.author}</p>
                                <p className="commentP">{this.state.comment}</p>
                            </div>
                                {this.props.auth.user.email === this.state.author ?
                                    <div className="editSet">
                                        <p onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Update</p>
                                        <p onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</p>
                                    </div>
                                    :
                                    <div></div>
                                }    
                        </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

var mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateComment})(Comment);
```

CommentsAction

```
import {GET_COMMENTS, LOADING_COMMENTS} from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getComments = (id) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadingComments());
  await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/itinerary/comments/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COMMENTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    })
    .catch(e  => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}

export const putComments = (id, data) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadingComments());
  await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/itinerary/comments/postcomment/${id}`, data)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COMMENTS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}

export const updateComment = (id, data) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(loadingComments());
  await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/itinerary/comments/updatecomment/${id}`, data)
  .then(res => {
     return res
  })
  .then(data => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_COMMENTS,
      payload: data.data
    })
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })

}

export const loadingComments = () => {
  return {
    type:  LOADING_COMMENTS
  }
}
```

CommentsReducer

```
import {GET_COMMENTS, LOADING_COMMENTS} from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
  comments: [],
  loadingComments: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_COMMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        comments: [...action.payload],
        loadingComments: false
      };
    case LOADING_COMMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingComments: true
      }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: podrias agregar la parte del render que hace falta del componente Activity

Comment: Ahi lo agregue junto con el js de comments

Comment: Hasta donde se no hay necesidad de que agreges los cometarios al estado interno del componente. Cada ves que un reducer actualiza el store este pasa el nuevo estado mediante los props de tus componente, por lo tanto accede a estos a traves de los props y no los asignes al state, de otra manera estarías produciendo un render inecesario (uno se produce cuand actualizas el store de redux y el segundo cuando llamas a setState)

Comment: Tambien estas usando un metodo obsoleto (componentWillUpdate) que será removido en futuras versine. Te recomiendo leer esto https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#legacy-lifecycle-methods

Answer (score 0):

prueba agregar una linea que vuelva a consultar los comentarios luego de actualizar ***await this.props.getComments(this.props.id)*** en el metodo ***handleSubmit***

```
class Activity extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            value:'',
            comments: [],
            activities: [],
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        console.log(this.state.comments)

    }


    componentWillUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { comments } = this.props.comments; 
   //Hasta aca en las props se ve que el comentario ya esta modificado

        if(prevProps.comments.comments !== comments) {
          this.setState({ comments: comments }) 
       //Al llegar aca entra correctamente al if pero no asigna nada al 
       //estado del componente
        }
      }

    async componentDidMount(){
        await this.props.getActivities(this.props.id)
        this.setState({activities: this.props.activity.activities})

        await this.props.getComments(this.props.id)
        this.setState({comments: this.props.comments.comments})
   //Aqui setea correctamente al estado
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmit =  async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            author: this.props.auth.user.userName,
            comment: this.state.value
        }

        await this.props.putComments(this.props.id, data);
        await this.props.getComments(this.props.id)

        this.setState({comments: this.props.comments.comments})
        //Aqui tambien
        this.setState({value: ''})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div id="carrouselAct">
                {this.props.activity.loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : 
                    <div>
                        <Carrousel act={this.state.activities} />
                        <div id="comments">
                            {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated ? 
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <input 
                                        type="text" 
                                        name="comment" 
                                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                                        placeholder=" add a comment..." 
                                        value={this.state.value} 
                                        id="commentInput">    
                                    </input>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                                </form> :
                                <div></div>
                            }
                            {this.state.comments.map((comment, i) =>
                                <Comment get={this.getComments} com={comment} id={this.props.id} index={i} />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div> 
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     activity: state.activity,
     comments: state.comments,
     auth: state.auth
});


export default connect (mapStateToProps,{getActivities, getComments, putComments})(Activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa otra accion para las actualizacines (UPDATE_COMENT por ejemplo). Si revisas tu codigo te daras cuenta que el reducer reemplaza todos los comentarios cuando recibe la accion GET_COMENTS, el problema es que se esta despachando la misma accion para las actualizaciones

```
export const updateComment = (id, data) => async dispatch => {
      dispatch(loadingComments());
      await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/itinerary/comments/updatecomment/${id}`, data)
      .then(res => {
         return res
      })
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_COMMENTS, //Utiliza otro valor
          payload: data.data //Imagino que esto es un simple comentario y no un array de comentarios como el reducer espera para la accion GET_COMMENTS. Esto va a causar problemas
        })
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })

    }
```

Solamente cambia el valor del atributo type de la accion de actualizacion y manejalo en el reducer de esta manera

```
case UPDATE_COMMENTS:
    return {
        ...state,
        comments: [
            ...state.comments.filter(c=>c.id !=action.payload.id),
            action.payload,
        ]
    }
```